# List all usernames from database from id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to list all username from database if the id exists. That code works fine in database `select * from users where id IN (1,2,3,4,5)`.

But in php it doesn't work. My php code is

```
$sql = "select * from users where id IN (1,2,3,4,5)"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
if ( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) { 
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
  echo $row["username"]; 
}
```

This php code only list one user name. I want to list all usernames. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks.

Comment: you only fetch one row. you have to loop over your rows......

Comment: loop through the results then after tht echo the rows

Comment: Is that where your hangin' now @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from users where id IN (1,2,3,4,5)"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
if ( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        echo $row["username"]."\n";
    } 
}
```

if you only fetch once, you will only get one row - obviously. so if you want all rows, you have to fetch as long as there are rows to fetch.

Comment: At least this one is less contentious

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and closed in php 7

Comment: Its a good idea to add some sort of _Stop using the `mysql_` API_ comment to your answer when the code is using `mysql_` to reduce the risk of a downvote

Comment: @RiggsFolly [You did...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134597/list-all-username-from-database-from-id?noredirect=1#comment67539092_40134597) haha! Unless you plan on deleting it *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I ment in the answer, but yea, just call me ___Mister Helpful___

Comment: @RiggsFolly Fair enough *"Mister Helpful"* ;-)

Comment: Thank you guys. @franz-gleichmann your code works fine thank you.
I understand I need to use mysqli. How can I change Franz's code to mysqli. sorry for my bad.